# Conflicting styles between datepicker & body table

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the default jQuery datepicker. I also got a table on the same page. whenever i try to style the table, the datepicker style changes with it. I am not able to change separate them with any class or id.

Please suggest where should i check for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for styling the table try using inline css this way js datepicker code will not get affected

Comment: Many thanks, it helped. Just one problem i am facing, the "td" getting its data from mysql database, so the td is inside php. and it is not taking the inline style like <table> or <th> any suggestion for that ?

Comment: if you can show the code can provide you a better solution . YOu can try this : <td class="my class">       </td> 

<style>
.myclass {color : red ;}
</style>

Comment: `<?php
while ($report=$records->fetch_assoc()) {      
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$report['Hourly']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$report['Ingress']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$report['Attempts']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";       
}`

Comment: <?php while ($report=$records->fetch_assoc()) { ?> 
<tr>
<td style"color: red"><?php echo  $report['Hourly'] ?> </td>
<td style"color: blue" ><?php echo $report['Attempts'] ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php  } ?>


Follow this approach

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific with your table styles. Worst case scenario you can use something like:

```
table:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar)
```

We can make more specific suggestions if you post the relevant bits of your html and css.